# Mutable stack in Racket

Tags: stack, lisp, macros, racket

I'm learning Racket and have implemented a mutable stack, which is just a bunch of wrappers around an underlying `struct` containing a size and buffer list (so it's not optimal, in terms of computational complexity). After consulting #racket and reading the first half of Greg Hendershott's [Fear of Macros](http://www.greghendershott.com/fear-of-macros/all.html), I was able to write the syntax transformations I wanted for my implementation.

```
(module stack racket
  (module stack-implementation racket
    (struct stack (size buffer) #:mutable)

    ;; size :: stack -> integer
    (define (size stack) (stack-size stack))

    ;; non-empty-stack? :: stack -> boolean
    (define (non-empty-stack? stack)
      (and
        (stack? stack)
        (positive? (stack-size stack))))

    ;; push! :: stack -> any (new item) -> integer (size)
    (define (push! stack item)
      (set-stack-buffer! stack
        (append (list item) (stack-buffer stack)))

      (set-stack-size! stack (+ (stack-size stack) 1))

      (stack-size stack))

    ;; pop! :: (non-empty) stack -> any (head)
    (define (pop! stack)
      (let ([head (car (stack-buffer stack))]
            [tail (cdr (stack-buffer stack))])

        (set-stack-buffer! stack tail)
        (set-stack-size! stack (- (stack-size stack) 1))

        head))

    ;; make
    (define-syntax-rule (make name)
      (define name (stack 0 '())))

    (provide make
             stack?
             (contract-out
               [size  (-> stack?            integer?)]
               [push! (-> stack? any/c      integer?)]
               [pop!  (-> non-empty-stack?  any)])))

  (require 'stack-implementation
           (for-syntax racket/syntax))

  ;; make-stack
  ;  Defines a stack under the specified symbol <name>
  ;  Plus defines <name>-size, <name>-empty?, <name>-push! and <name>-pop!
  (define-syntax (make-stack stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ name)
        (with-syntax ([(size-fn empty-fn push-fn pop-fn)
                       (map (lambda (fn) (format-id stx "~a-~a" #'name fn))
                            '("size" "empty?" "push!" "pop!"))])
          #'(begin
              (make name)
              (define (size-fn)      (size name))
              (define (empty-fn)     (zero? (size-fn)))
              (define (push-fn item) (push! name item))
              (define (pop-fn)       (pop!  name))))]))

  (provide make-stack
           stack?))
```

I'm completely new to Racket and Lisp, so I'm guessing there are many improvements I can make here (e.g., the duplication in the macro where I define the helper function IDs), besides using a better underlying data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many Lisp programs use cons cells quite liberally instead of adding a
separate stack structure, in that sense your concerns about complexity
are probably a bit less critical.  Since the stack is also carrying the
length of the list it actually supports at least the additional size
operator quite well.  Of course writing more code for an underlying
(resizable) vector *could* make sense, but again I wouldn't count on
that being necessary.

For the code I only have minor suggestions, as it's pretty well written
and clear what each part means; while I'm not that familiar with Racket
it's easily readable to me.

- For the pattern `(+/- x 1)` there are also the functions `add1` and
  `sub1` which could be used.
- The `non-empty-stack?` could just check whether the `buffer` is
  `null?` or `empty?` instead.  `positive?` sounds like there's some
  risk that the stack size might get negative for some reason.  For the
  same reason the contract can probably also be tightened to check for
  non-negative integers.
- `(append (list x) y)` is a bit shorter as `(cons x y)`.

Comment: `add1` and `sub1`: that's what I was looking for! I kept trying `inc` and `dec` to no avail. Thank you :)